# How to remove the repeated data in the pickerview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have array with 10 data. I'm showing the value of that array in the pickerview. Out of 10 values in the array 4 data are same for example there are apple for 4 times. How to remove the repeated data and show only one time apple in the picker.

Comment: you should remove duplicate data from array

Answer (score 0):

you can remove duplicate data from your array like:

```
NSArray *cleanedArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:yourArray] allObjects];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take another Array and insert distinct value in that, then use that array as your data source for the picker.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before assigning it to picker-view.

```
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)
        for (int j=i+1; j<[array count]; j++)
            if ( [[array objectAtIndex:i] isEqual:[array objectAtIndex:j]])
                [array removeObjectAtIndex:j];
```

Comment: Since you are removing the array whenever the data is duplicate , this could possibly result in a crash during the next iteration of the i loop as there will be no data in the removed index position

Comment: No it wont. because i just gave the array count as condition.